# Why does setInterval not work inside of my jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, setinterval

```
(function ( $ ) {

$.fn.gallery = function() {
    var images = $(this);
    return setInterval($.proxy(changeImage(images)), 500);
};

var i = 0;
var changeImage = function(images){
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    var _images = images;
    console.log(_images.length);
}


}( jQuery ));

$(function(){
    $('.home-gallery').gallery();
});
```

This code gives me the console.log but does not repeat every 500 milliseconds. I only get the console.log once for "i" and once for "_images.length". After that it doesn't repeat.

EDIT: I removed the $.proxy bit and it's still not repeating

```
$.fn.gallery = function() {
    var images = $(this);
    return setInterval(changeImage(images), 500);
};
```

Comment: `$.proxy(changeImage(images))` is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `$.proxy` correctly, nor do you even need it here.  Just, simply, do:

```
return setInterval(function(){
    changeImage(images)
}, 500);
```

Comment: @user1426594: Your edited post is still incorrect.  Check the answer.  Notice how I'm passing `setInterval` a function.  You are calling `changeImage` and passing its return value to `setInterval`.

Comment: that fixed it but I'm not sure why. I've always been doing setInterval by simply passing a function. I'm not sure why it only ran once, can you please explain?

Comment: @user1426594: Because when you do `setInterval(changeImage(images), 500)`, you are *not* passing a function.  You are calling it and passing its return value.  If you did `return setInterval(changeImage, 500);`, then you'd be passing the function, but when it was called, it wouldn't have the `images` passed.  That's why you need to pass it an anonymous function that calls `changeImage` with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass something like that. You have to wrap it inside a anonymous function.

You should do this:

```
setInterval(function () {
  changeImage(images);
}, 500);
```

You don't need `$.proxy` here as Rocket Hazmat suggested in the comment.

Comment: Close, but not quite.  You don't need the `$.proxy` here.  `$.proxy` is like `Function.bind`, it returns a function.  It's meant to be used like `var func = $.proxy(changeImage, null, images);`, and then you can call `func()`, but it's not needed here, because `changeImage` doesn`t use `this`.

Answer (score -1):

Both answers are correct, but incomplete. 
The first argument for `setInterval()` needs to be either a function or a string, so wrapping it in an anonymous function is a good start.

Next since `setInterval()` fires again after a timer, the scope changes and the variable 'images' will no longer exist.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
$.fn.gallery = function() {
    var images = $(this);
    return setInterval((function(images){
        return function() {
            $.proxy(changeImage(images));
        };
    })(images), 500);
};
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be true. console.log(images.length) is outputting the correct number on every call

Comment: Oh yep your right. My mistake... my excuse is it's late here hah!

Comment: No, that's not true.  `images` will *stay* in memory since there is still a reference to it.  Also, you are using `$.proxy` incorrectly.

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is only when you are calling `setTimeout` in a loop and are trying to access the (ever-changing) loop variable.  It's not an issue here.

Comment: Yeah Rocket your right, I just had a brain fart. What's the normal practice here, do I delete my response? <-- stack noob

Comment: @Akurn: Up to you.  You can delete it if you wish.